# I am trying to pivot a json file using pandas to be in a specific format. I want to pivot it on certain columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

So I tried searching on the web to find a way in which I can convert the following json.

```
{
"eTask_ID": "100",
"Organization": "Power",
"BidID": "2.00",
"Project": "IPP - C",
"Forecast%": "67",
"Sponsor": "Jon R",
"IsActive": "1",
"InternalOrder": "null",
"Forecast": "null",
"BidStatus": "null",
"ProjectNotes": "null",
"EstimateTypeCode": "null",
"Start": "null",
"SponsoringDistrict": "null",
"LocationState": "null",
"Finish": "null",
"AreaManager": "null",
"CTG Vendor": "null"
}
```

to the one like below.

```
{
"eTask_ID": "100",
"Organization": "Power",
"BidID": "2.00",
"Project": "IPP - C",
"Attribute":"Forecast%",
"AttrValue":"67",
},
{
"eTask_ID": "100",
"Organization": "Power",
"BidID": "2.00",
"Project": "IPP - C",
"Attribute":"Sponsor",
"AttrValue":"Jon R",
},
{
"eTask_ID": "100",
"Organization": "Power",
"BidID": "2.00",
"Project": "IPP - C",
"Attribute":"IsActive",
"AttrValue":"1",
},
...
```

Now here if you see all the attributes apart from the first four are getting converted into Attribute and AttributeValue and getting their own records.

I have tried searching for a solution on the web but I am still trying to find a solution.

Please help if anyone can.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.melt`:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    
    out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').T \
            .melt(['eTask_ID', 'Organization', 'BidID', 'Project'], 
                  var_name='Attribute', value_name='AttrValue') \
            .to_json(orient='records', indent=4)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(out)
[
    {
        "eTask_ID":100,
        "Organization":"Power",
        "BidID":2,
        "Project":"IPP - C",
        "Attribute":"Forecast%",
        "AttrValue":67
    },
    {
        "eTask_ID":100,
        "Organization":"Power",
        "BidID":2,
        "Project":"IPP - C",
        "Attribute":"Sponsor",
        "AttrValue":"Jon R"
    },
    {
        "eTask_ID":100,
        "Organization":"Power",
        "BidID":2,
        "Project":"IPP - C",
        "Attribute":"IsActive",
        "AttrValue":1
    },
    {
        "eTask_ID":100,
        "Organization":"Power",
        "BidID":2,
        "Project":"IPP - C",
        "Attribute":"InternalOrder",
        "AttrValue":"null"
    },
    {
        "eTask_ID":100,
        "Organization":"Power",
        "BidID":2,
        "Project":"IPP - C",
        "Attribute":"Forecast",
        "AttrValue":"null"
    },
    {
        "eTask_ID":100,
        "Organization":"Power",
        "BidID":2,
        "Project":"IPP - C",
        "Attribute":"BidStatus",
        "AttrValue":"null"
    },
    {
        "eTask_ID":100,
        "Organization":"Power",
        "BidID":2,
        "Project":"IPP - C",
        "Attribute":"ProjectNotes",
        "AttrValue":"null"
    },
    {
        "eTask_ID":100,
        "Organization":"Power",
        "BidID":2,
        "Project":"IPP - C",
        "Attribute":"EstimateTypeCode",
        "AttrValue":"null"
    },
    {
        "eTask_ID":100,
        "Organization":"Power",
        "BidID":2,
        "Project":"IPP - C",
        "Attribute":"Start",
        "AttrValue":"null"
    },
    {
        "eTask_ID":100,
        "Organization":"Power",
        "BidID":2,
        "Project":"IPP - C",
        "Attribute":"SponsoringDistrict",
        "AttrValue":"null"
    },
    {
        "eTask_ID":100,
        "Organization":"Power",
        "BidID":2,
        "Project":"IPP - C",
        "Attribute":"LocationState",
        "AttrValue":"null"
    },
    {
        "eTask_ID":100,
        "Organization":"Power",
        "BidID":2,
        "Project":"IPP - C",
        "Attribute":"Finish",
        "AttrValue":"null"
    },
    {
        "eTask_ID":100,
        "Organization":"Power",
        "BidID":2,
        "Project":"IPP - C",
        "Attribute":"AreaManager",
        "AttrValue":"null"
    },
    {
        "eTask_ID":100,
        "Organization":"Power",
        "BidID":2,
        "Project":"IPP - C",
        "Attribute":"CTG Vendor",
        "AttrValue":"null"
    }
]
```